On Nintendo Switch, can you get Minecraft Story Mode S2 as of now?
On Nintendo Switch, can you get Minecraft Story Mode S2 EP1-5 as of now?
I found Minecraft Story Mode Season 1, and I found this.
But I don't know if I can still download episodes 2-5 as it says in the description, does it still work or is there a cartridge that contains all 5 already? I think some Reddit posts said something about it, but I couldn't find any more information.

It should still work. They lost a major investor, forcing them to shut down and stop making games. If you get season 1, get the complete adventure version instead of the season pass.

So the one I linked is the S1 complete adventure but does it include all the episodes or is it the same as in S2 where you have to download them via internet?

And in my second link it is the S2 one that says you download them when they come out, so if you are correct I should be able to play all 5 episodes and with the S1 Complete Adventure I can play all 13?

You should be able to.

read this post: https://www.minecraft.net/article/important-minecraft--story-mode-information
